# So many errors 'Bareword found where operator expected' occured in my ruby script

Tags: ruby

I upgraded ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0

After upgrading, I cannot run my script anymore because there are so many errors.

**UPDATE**
I updated the beginning part of my script.

**errors**

```
Bareword found where operator expected at D:\ex\report.rb line 12, near "$0
  def"
        (Missing operator before def?)
Bareword found where operator expected at D:\ex\report.rb line 18, near "usage"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at D:\ex\report.rb line 19.
syntax error at D:\ex\report.rb line 5, near "Encoding::UTF_8 require "
Execution of D:\jenkins_lab_a\asap.ex\asap-report-apps.rb aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**script**

```
# coding: utf-8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

require './lib/utils'
require './lib/klocwork'
require './lib/td'
require 'fileutils'
require 'logger'

if __FILE__ == $0
  def usage
    warn 'usage: report.rb [a] [b] [c]'
    warn "ex) report.rb a b c"
    exit
  end
  puts "report.rb start"
  usage if ARGV.size < 3   

end
```

I can see errors like this all over the script.
But I never changed my script and It is working well in the previous version.

So I think that I missed any environmental settings

Could you let me know what I can check to resolve this issue?

Comment: I would assume that you have some code in the file before the posted script which are the actual source of the syntax errors. They are just reported here because the code before is probably syntactically valid but still wrong. Thus, please post your *complete* script.

Comment: I updated my script and error @Holger Just

Comment: I am trying to do other approach. I think this error may occur because of wrong install. (maybe, my colleague seems to skip check-box related to .rb) I will update the result

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't Ruby error messages. You aren't running your Ruby files with a Ruby interpreter. There's no concept of "bareword" in Ruby, and semicolons are entirely optional, so it wouldn't report about them either.

Comment: It looks like the script is executed by a Perl interpreter.